# WatchKit Menu - Objective C - Menu does not fire

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, watchos

I'm trying to create a simple Watch App.
I've added a MENU to the interface.storyboard. 
I selected the MENU ITEM and dragged it to the InterfaceController.m and created the following

```
@implementation InterfaceController

    -(IBAction)Menu1{
       NSLog(@"Menu 1 clicked");
    }
```

When I run it and click the Menu option.  The menu closes but this code never fires. Any ideas what is wrong.

thanks in advance

Comment: try to add break point and debug the app.

Comment: I added a break point .. it never hits.

Comment: Sent action is Menu1  connected  to InferfaceController